# Import crypto-js in an angular 2 project (created with angular-cli)

Tags: angular, cryptojs

I'm trying to import crypto-js in my angular2 project.

I followed several SO questions and also [angular-cli guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs), but at the end I still have the error **Cannot find module 'crypto-js'**

What I tried :

`npm install crypto-js --save`

and

`typings install dt~crypto-js --global --save`

then I modified the file **angular-cli-build.js**

```
var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)',
      'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'crypto-js/**/*.+(js|js.map)'
    ]
  });
};
```

and the file **src/system-config.ts**

```
const map: any = {
    'crypto-js': 'vendor/crypto-js'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
    'crypto-js': {
        format: 'cjs'
    }
};
```

After using

`import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';`

I still have my error. Did I miss something ?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/encrypt-decrypt-app check this example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it. I just download the [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/4869992bc079b88280b9ff91213528904109e8ae/crypto-js) file in typings/crypto-js/ and then I add the line `/// <reference path="../../typings/crypto-js/crypto-js.d.ts" />` before importing CryptoJS.

Comment: That link doesnt work... I used [link](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/4869992bc079b88280b9ff91213528904109e8ae/crypto-js)  and added that files in: node_modules/crypto-js  then on my class I imported:    import * as CryptoJS from '../../../node_modules/crypto-js'

Answer (score 31):

This may help you:

---

```
$ npm install crypto-js --save
$ npm install @types/crypto-js --save-dev
```

then:

```
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
```

or

```
import CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try following as a solution:

```
1. npm install --save @types/crypto-js


2. import { AES } from "crypto-js";


3. AES.encrypt('my message', 'secret key');
```

Comment: I use SHA3 and I find out that:
`import { SHA3 } from "crypto-js";` makes the dist.js a little fat than
`import * as SHA3 from 'crypto-js/sha3';`. It's about 100KB.
I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `Package.JSON` file.

```
"browser": {
    "crypto": false
}
```

Doing so will tell your application when you run `ng serve` to not to bundle your Crypto library to serve to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Add the script path in *angular-cli.json* file after installing *cryto-js* & @types/crypto-js

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/crypto-js/crypto-js.js"
]
```