# TypeError: Cannot read property 'random' of undefined - crypto-js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cryptojs

I'm using `crypto-js` inside `reactjs` and everything works fine on localhost.
but on server with chrome I got this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'random' of undefined
```

on firefox:

```
TypeError: "r is undefined"
```

my code:

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

console.log('text',text); //printed on console as well
var p = randomString(10) 
console.log('p',p) //printed on console as well
var c = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text,p).toString(); // error line
console.log('crypted',c+p)//not printed !
```

my function:

```
  function setWindow(text){
    console.log('text',text);
    var p = randomString(10)
    console.log('p',p)
    var c = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text,p).toString();
    console.log('crypted',c+p)
    return c+p;
  }
```

---

```
"crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
```

I don't know where is my problem! I removed `node_modules`, but I got the same error.
my site:
http://posweb.ccg24.com/signin

**updated**

```
  function randomString(length) {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
      text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
  }
```

Comment: Try `npm install` in your project folder on the server.

Comment: yes, I tested it again and again.

Comment: Which library are you using for randomString ?

Comment: I added `randomString` to question, but the error refers to random function inside the library. I think.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072744/math-random-javascript-function-undefined-on-chrome

Comment: Can you try var c = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text.toString(),p).toString(); @S.M_Emamian

Comment: @Mayank Bansal done.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian did it worked?

Comment: unfortunately  No.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate random without using `Math.random`

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
var p;
function randomString(length) {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

 var text= _.sampleSize(possible , length).join('');

  return text;
}

function setWindow(text){
    console.log('text',text);
     p = randomString(10)
    console.log('p',p)
    var c = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text,p).toString();
    console.log('crypted',c+p)
    return c+p;
  }



var ciphertext=setWindow("plain text");
var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext.toString(), p);
var plaintext = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

console.log("decrypte",plaintext);
```

```js
function randomString(length) {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
      text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
  }




function setWindow(text){
 

    console.log('text',text);
    var p = randomString(10)
    console.log('p',p)
    var c =CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text,p);
    console.log('crypted',c+p)
    return c+p;
}
var text="Plain Text";
setWindow(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

The code here:https://repl.it/@ibrahimth/LastSatisfiedBrain

Comment: my problem isn't for my `randomString` function. because I got the correct response on my function.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian try it now.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian first check this if you have a problem:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38479667/import-crypto-js-in-an-angular-2-project-created-with-angular-cli

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
```